# Derive Stirling's Approximation for Beta Function

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, gamma-function, beta-function

I am trying to derive a Stirling's approximation for the [Multivariate Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Multivariate_beta_function). This does not seem very hard, but I cannot even derive the Stirling's approximation for the usual Beta function. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Approximation), we have:

$B(x,y) \sim \sqrt{2\pi} \frac{x^{x-\frac{1}{2}}y^{y-\frac{1}{2}}}{(x+y)^{x+y-\frac{1}{2}}}$

I thought I could just use the Stirling's formula for $\Gamma(x)$ and the relation between $\Gamma$ and $B$.

That is:

$\Gamma(x) \sim \sqrt{2\pi} (x-1)^{x-\frac{1}{2}} e^{1-x}$.

From here:

$B(x,y) =  \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)} \sim \sqrt{2\pi} \frac{(x-1)^{x-\frac{1}{2}}(y-1)^{y-\frac{1}{2}}}{(x+y-1)^{x+y-\frac{1}{2}}} $

This is close but different from the formula I find on Wikipedia (and other sources). Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $$
\Gamma (x) = \Gamma (x + 1)/x=x!/x \sim \sqrt {2\pi } x^{x + 1/2} e^{ - x} /x = \sqrt {2\pi } x^{x - 1/2} e^{ - x} 
$$

Comment: That will do. Thanks!